# Esc key not getting recognized in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, keypress, esc-key

For some reason this script isn't working in Firefox:

```
document.onkeydown=function keypress(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        window.location = "/edit"
    };
};
```

It works fine in Chrome, but for some reason it's not working in Firefox.

Basically, what it does is load the `/edit` page when you press the escape key.

Comment: Works for me in FF5: http://jsfiddle.net/Tm2PZ/

Comment: trying running `console.log(e)`. Check the output to check if something is occuring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use:

```
document.onkeydown=function keypress(e) {
  e=(e||window.event);  
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        try{e.preventDefault();}//Non-IE
        catch(x){e.returnValue=false;}//IE
        window.location = "/edit";
    };
}
```

The default-action for <kbd>ESC</kbd> is to stop loading the page,
so you must prevent from this behaviour, otherwise you cannot change the location.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/CsqgE/ (Click into the result-frame first before using <kbd>ESC</kbd>)

But however, you really should use another key.
A user expects that the loading of the current page stops if he uses <kbd>ESC</kbd> , nothing else.

Comment: Ah. I didn't know about that keyboard shortcut. I chose Escape because I know SquareSpace uses that, I'll have to try and figure out another key.

Answer (score 0):

The event handler is working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Tm2PZ/

I suspect the lcoation you're setting is not valid.

Try setting `window.location.href` instead.

Comment: @Dr.Molle: Agree with you. Deleted my comments.

Answer (score 0):

**if you don't use** **'Escape keyup or Escape keydown'** 
 for other things in your code, **you can use 'keyup' to replace keypress****

```
 document.body.addEventListener( 'keyup', function (e) {
        e=(e||window.event);
        if (e.key == "Escape") {
            console.log('escape is pressed');
        }    
    },false );
```

**e.keyCode is depreciate**, use **e.key**, add "console.log(e.key)"
 in your listener if you want to get key name 
**it is better, because it adapts to the keyboard which does not have the same composition** and e.keyCode does not adapt